# Limit Dynamic Form elements upto 10 Records

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a solution where User can refer their friends details & data will be stored in DB

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery121min.js'></script>

  <style type='text/css'>
    .extraPersonTemplate {
    display:none;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('<div/>', {
         'class' : 'extraPerson', html: GetHtml()
     }).appendTo('#container');
     $('#addRow').click(function () {
           $('<div/>', {
               'class' : 'extraPerson', html: GetHtml()
     }).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');

     });
 })
 function GetHtml()
{
      var len = $('.extraPerson').length;
    var $html = $('.extraPersonTemplate').clone();
    $html.find('[name=friendname]')[0].name="friendname" + len;
    $html.find('[name=friendemail]')[0].name="friendemail" + len;
    $html.find('[name=friendmob]')[0].name="friendmob" + len;
    return $html.html();    
}
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<input class="span3" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" name="yourname">
 <input class="span3" placeholder="Your Email" type="text" name="youremail">
<input class="span3" placeholder="Your Mobile" type="text" name="yourmob">
  <div class="extraPersonTemplate">
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input class="span3" placeholder="Friend Name" type="text" name="friendname">
        <input class="span3" placeholder="Friend Email" type="text" name="friendemail">
        <input class="span3" placeholder="friend Mobile" type="text" name="friendmob">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<a href="#" id="addRow"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add another Friend</p></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Code works fine On Hitting Link it adds extra records

Now In DB I have  following fields

```
YourName, YourMobile, YourEmail, F1name,F1mob,F1email ....... f10name,f10mob,f10email
```

So Now I want to limit the above Code to have only maximum 10 entries,

So I want to limit the dynamic form elements only for 10 friend details.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#addRow').click(function () {        
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'extraPerson',
        html: GetHtml()
    }).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');
    var len = $("#container").find(".extraPerson").length;
    if(len == 10){
        $('#addRow').hide();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/89RjR/)

Comment: Perfect. 1upvode + accpeted

Answer (score 1):

Check using length:

```
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    if($('#container .extraPerson').length >= 10) return;
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'extraPerson',
        html: GetHtml()
    }).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');

});
```

Comment: Thanks Your Code also Works 1+ upvote.. Accepted Hiral's Answer for a reason Her code is more specific

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly....

You already know how many fields you have for adding friends in GetHtml:

```
var len = $('.extraPerson').length;
```

So all you need to do is incorporate that into your #addRow .click function.

```
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    if($('.extraPerson').length <= 10) {
        $('<div/>', {'class' : 'extraPerson', html: GetHtml() }).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        //Add some means of notification that they can't add more people
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Your code helped me to make basics better 1+ upvote :)